# Handle side effects caused by duplicate POST requests

Tags: web-services, rest, post, duplicates, idempotent

Let's say we have a web service that creates and updates meeting room bookings. Updates can change various aspects of a booking, such as time and room number.

Let's imagine that user's network connection to the service may not be reliable (e.g. mobile network), and two users A and B try to update the same booking sequentially.

User A sends a POST request to change the meeting time to 2pm, the request reaches the server and server processed the request successfully. However, the response back to User A gets lost due to network connection, and User A thinks the request fails.

Before User A tries again, User B sends her request to change the meeting time to 2:30pm, and it succeeds and responds to User B successfully.

Now User A retries (perhaps automatically) the same request again, and this time both the request and response succeed without a problem. In other words, the meeting time is changed back to 2pm.

In the hypothetical scenario above, User A's duplicated requests cause User B's request be overwritten, and result an incorrect state on the server-side.

One possible but naive solution is to set a ID for each every request on the client, and this ID does not change if a request is simply re-tried/re-sent. Then on the server-side, the server maintains a collection of received request IDs and checks for duplicates.

What are the better techniques or methods for solving this problem?

Comment: See if PRG (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This a common problem with concurrent users. One way to solve it is to enforce conditional requests, requiring clients to send the `If-Unmodified-Since` header with the `Last-Modified` value for the resource they are attempting to change. That guarantees nobody else changed it between the last time they checked and now. In your case, this would prevent A from overwritten B's changes.

For instance, user A wants to change the meeting time. It sends a GET request for the meeting resource and keep the value of the `Last-Modified` response header. Then, it sends the `POST` request with the `Last-Modified` value in the `If-Unmodified-Since` header. Following your example, this request actually succeeds, but the response is lost.

If A repeats the request immediately, it will fail with `412 Precondition Failed`, since the condition is no longer valid.

If in the meantime B does the same thing and changes the meeting time again, when A tries to repeat the request, without checking for the current `Last-Modified` value corresponding to B's changes, it also fails with `412 Precondition Failed`.

Comment: thanks for the answer. Could you please elaborate the usage of `If-Unmodified-Since` and `Last-Modified` in this case? Which side sets which header?

Comment: So does this imply that, on the server-side, a timestamp needs to be updated for the resource (in this case, the details of each meeting) every time there is an update? And when any client sends a POST request with its own version of `Last-Modified` value inside `If-Unmodified-Since` header field, the server will check this value against the stored timestamp for the requested resource. If the timestamp is after the `Last-Modified` value, then the server should not process the request and should respond `412 Precondition Failed`. Is this understanding correct?

Comment: The client doesn't send its own version of `Last-Modified`. It should issue a GET request and use the value returned in that response in the `If-Unmodified-Since` header of the POST request. If the currently stored timestamp is after the `If-Unmodified-Since` value, the server should fail with `412 Precondition Failed`. If the client doesn't send the `If-Unmodified-Since` header, the server should fail with `428 Precondition Required`.